# How many solutions are $ a+b+c+d+e = 10 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: How many solutions are 
there to the equation 
$$ a+b+c+d+e = 10 $$
where $a,b,c,d,e\in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: I would appreciate if you could tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Can $a,b,c,d,e$ be used only once?

Comment: From my comment, can $a,b,c,d,e$ be used only once?

If yes, then note that $4+3+2+1=10$, and hence, there is only one solution.

If not, then
$$1+1+1+3+7,\quad 2+2+1+3+2\quad, \mathrm{etc.}$$ could work. Again what have you tried?

Comment: It is possible to repeat

Comment: Small enough that you could just bruteforce it if you didn't want to think too hard. 381.

Comment: Hey remember that time someone listed all 381 solutions... yeah, that was crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you find the coefficient of the $10^{\text{th}}$ degree term in this polynomial?
$$p(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^5=\frac{(x^5-1)^5}{(x-1)^5}$$

Comment: +1 A bit overkill but whenever one can find an excuse to use generating functions...

Answer (score 1):

Outline of a solution:

1. Find all integer partitions of $10$ into at most $5$ elements with maximal value $4$.
2. For each such partition, compute the number of distinct permutations of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical combinatorial problem. Imagine you have five varieties of pastries $a,b,c,d,e$ and you have to make up a box of $10$ pastries with the condition that you cannot make use of more than $4$ of each variety.

**First think of it without this restriction of no more than $4$ of each variety.**

Without this restriction this can be thought of as the number of ways to arrange $10$ zeros and $4$ ones. You may think of each one as a divider between the zeros. For example, $00100010000110$  means you have created a box of $10$ pastries with $2$ of type $a$, $3$ of type $b$, $4$ of type $c$, none of type $d$ and $1$ of type $e$.

So the number of pastry boxes = number of binary strings of length $14$ with exactly $10$ zeros (or same as exactly $4$ ones). and this is equal to $\binom{14}{10}$.

Once you get this then you need to subtract the number of solutions possible when at least one of the variables is $\geq 5$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We outline the strategy, and leave it to you to put the pieces together.

You are probably familiar with the number of solutions of $a+b+c+d+e$ in non-negative integers. This is solved by a technique often called [Stars and Bars.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) For the record, the number is $\binom{14}{4}$.

We need to take away from this the number of solutions where one or more of the variables is $\ge 5$.

The solutions where one of the numbers is $\ge 6$ are easy to count. There are $5$ ways to choose which of $a,b,c,d,e$ is $\ge 6$. And given that (say) $a\ge 6$, the number of solutions is the number of solutions of $a+b+c+d+e$ in non-negative integers. That's a Stars and Bars problem.

Now we count the solutions where one or more of the variables is equal to $5$. There are $\binom{5}{2}$ solutions where two of the numbers are $5$.

For exactly one of the numbers equal to $5$, things are more complicated. Which one it is can be chosen in $5$ ways. Then we need to solve $x+y+z+w=5$, with none of the entries equal to $5$. This is the number of solutions in non-negative integers of $x+y+z+w=5$, minus the $4$ solutions in which one of the variables is $5$.